# Finding the density of $\max(X-c, 0)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

In general, if I have been given a RV $X$ with pdf $f(x)$ and I want to derive the density and mean of a new RV $Y = \max(X-c, 0)$ , with $c$ being some constant, for example $10$, how would I do it?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please include your own thoughts, the effort made so far, and the specific difficulties that got you stuck. Otherwise this question is likely to be closed via community votes or just be ignored.

Comment: What is the distribution of $X$?

Comment: $$
E[(X-c)^+] = \int_c^\infty (x-c) f(x)\ \mathsf dx
$$